# discord.py change channel description and name

Tags: python, discord.py

Goal is to change channel description and name directly from python code.
With the code mentioned bellow I'm able to change name but for some reason description wont update.
What am I missing here.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import datetime
from dotenv import load_dotenv  
import os
load_dotenv() 

TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
 
bot = discord.Bot("!", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord!')
    bot_channel = bot.get_channel(int(os.getenv('CHANNEL_ID')))
    await bot_channel.edit(name = 'ChannelName'
        , description = 'ChannelDescription')
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

According to [API Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.edit) there should be option to edit description.

```
py-cord 2.2.2
discord 1.7.3
discord.py 2.0.1
```

Comment: Not sure if related, but those first two packages are probably breaking your discord.py installation (we get situations like this on a daily basis in the discord.py server). Uninstall all three (and anything else that is Discord-related), and reinstall **only** discord.py.

Comment: @stijndcl Interesting, when i left only discord.py module now I'm getting  `module 'discord' has no attribute 'Bot' `

Comment: @stijndcl Switched to `Client` and still same issue

Comment: For reference, it's `discord.ext.commands.Bot` in `discord.py`.

Comment: The ratelimits for updating channel descriptions are pretty strict, and you're doing it in `on_ready` so it's probably been fired quite frequently in development. Also, you should never be making API requests in `on_ready` in the first place. Why exactly are you trying to update the description when the bot is ready?

Comment: @stijndcl Basically i need wrapped function which will except parameter chanel_id and chanel_name so i can send request to change it. I have no other experience so i used bot ready and when its ready make the change and shut down. But having few issues with that also

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is I pointed to wrong API documentation related to guilds.

We need to use `topic = 'ChannelDescription'` instead of `description = 'ChannelDescription'`

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import datetime
from dotenv import load_dotenv  
import os
load_dotenv() 

TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
 
bot = discord.Bot("!", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} has connected to Discord!')
    bot_channel = bot.get_channel(int(os.getenv('CHANNEL_ID')))
    await bot_channel.edit(name = 'ChannelName'
        , topic = 'ChannelDescription')
bot.run(TOKEN)
```